# Circuit for switching higher load using transitor with signal being 300 Hz PWM

Tags: transistors, three-phase, load

EDIT: DO NOT even think about using the naive example of a circuit to switch three phase. As someone rightly pointed out this is a complex issue and will almost certainly result in burnt finger or death :S without being a very competent engineer. I am a hobbyist and this was meant to get some feedback and guidance on the subject

EDIT: Just found out about triacs so replace NPN with triac. What else do I need to know about?

I am looking for some help in designing a very simple circuit using a transistor to switch a load based on a 300 hz pulse width modulation circuit. Could someone give me some guidance on values etc for the componenets.

I think the circuit should be something like this:

[image]

Could someone give me (ideally and I would really be very pleased) the values for RB, do I need that RL or is the motor itself the load? and do I need anything else?

Comment: You can't control AC with transistors. And is that really three-phase?

Comment: I have just found out about triacs and yes it struck me as I finished the question. Yes it will be 3 phase

Comment: For PWM triacs aren't good either. After you turn them on they will remain on until the next zero-crossing. You'll need MOSFETs, but even for single phase this is no easy job. MOSFETs, like transistors, are polarized devices, and can't readily switch AC. 3-phase AC PWM is particularly difficult.

Comment: To control motors powered with AC you need to have complex biasing arrangemants, you need to give more info about your application.  IT is not true that you have to use MOSFETS or Triacs, you can use BJT transistors (it's more difficult though)   There are also devices called GTO's Gate Turn Off transistors, which are like a combination of a FET (or transistor) and a Triac.

Comment: What voltage, what power or current. What is the AC freqnency?  In your drawing you have RL,  I assume that is present due to a misunderstanding or is it something else?

Comment: Thanks for the advice - anyone know of a package that is designed for this kind of situation?

Comment: @JasonMorgan yes it is misunderstanding - I am trying to find out what the problems are (which by the looks of what I have read so far are many)

Comment: There is an excessively high chance of killing yourself before you learn enough if you aim at any "doing" before you have learned more about the subject. A scattergun of comments: Motro shown with 2 leads will not talk to 3 phase as is. If you have more leds (and you must have) theh the diagram should not be a block diagram that is unable to actually built. You draw an NPN transistor and show its symbol but talk of TRIACs. Diagram must match reality. You do not say what you are trying to do and we can't tell. How do you know the circuit is simple (it may be)?  Why 300 Hz? Who says? Details pse

Comment: @PaulSullivan - a package designed for this sort of situation is called a coffin :-(. There is liable to be a very straight forward solution to your problem which we can provided once you tell us what "this sort of situation" is.

Comment: Is this the sort of thing you are trying to design? [link](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/75073.pdf)  I should add that controlling 3phase mains using PWM is by no means simple.....

Comment: @JasonMorgan Thanks I think (having quickly scan read) that the link is correct. Basically I need to feed a PWM signal @ 10v and lets say at 150hz (with 300Hz being maximum) the motor will have 50% power. Is this what the package you linked to describes?

Comment: @Paul - Note that the circuit Jason linked to can't do PWM. That's even more complex.

Comment: @stevenh - any guidance please (or packages you know of)

Comment: what about this? http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8312.pdf

Comment: @Paul - Yes, I've seen that one. But it creates the 3 phases from a DC power supply, it's not working with 3-phase mains.

Comment: @PaulSullivan - why don'y you tell us what you actually want to do instead of wanting to look at random circuits and iC's. You are so far wasting your time and hours. More usually than not when a question follows the lines this one has it turns out that what the questioner wants is quite different than what everyone thinks. What voltage? What power? Where is the 3 phase coming from? Does it always have 50% power but speed varies? - possible but not usual? What does it do? One or many? More ...?

Comment: Lokk at [this circuit](http://www.innovatia.com/Design_Center/DC_images/image254.gif) and note the word "simple" is used.  We MAY be able to suggest something much simpler but do not know the requirement. Look at [these many 3 phase motor control circuit diagrams](http://goo.gl/V7Vqa). Most are probably far far far more complex than you want or need. Until we know what you want or need we cannot provide best help.

Comment: Also, is that motor in star or delta? In star should be more doable, because the phases would at least have the same reference. In delta you don't even have that.

Comment: Two comments: 1. Like others have said, what are you requirements (what problem are you trying to solve)?  Reading between the lines, it sounds like you may be trying to make a 3phase motor drive.  This typically isn't a DIY project and is a poor first project for a hobbyist.

Comment: Comment 2: There are many choices for switch devices and the right one depends on the power level and performance.  MOSFETs are good for low voltage/power (say <kW's)  IGBT's are typical for most "industrial" applications (kW's - MW's).  Thyristors (GTO, IGCT, MCT, etc) are used at the big stuff (MW+)

Comment: You asked for guidance. Don't build anything that deals with more than 12 V, 0.5 A, in the next half year or so. You need to learn many things before that.

Comment: Everybody - thanks I take on board all your answers and will try not to fry myself :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, nobody can give you a value for Rb since the circuit it is in makes no sense whatsoever.

No, you probably don't need Rl, although again, it is in a nonsensical circuit so it is hard to tell what you intend.  However, you should not need any explicit additional resistive load in series with the motor.

Yes, you need something else.  It's impossible to say what since you haven't provided a clear description of what you want.  However, it is clear that the circuit you show isn't going to do anything like motor control.  At best it will function as a pyrotechnic transducer, once.

Obvious things wrong with your circuit:

You say "3 phase AC", but there are only 2 wires.  3 phase requires at least 3 wires, sometimes four.

You mention a 3 phase motor, but that motor only has two connections, so it can't possibly be three phase.

You say the power is AC, but are trying to use a single NPN to switch it.  At best that will turn on for half the wave, but bipolar transistors are generally not designed for large reverse voltages.  A single bipolar here makes no sense.

I have no idea what you think Rl is supposed to do.

There are just too many things wrong here to try to fix.

Comment: The accepted answer is an answer that says that the question makes no sense :)

Comment: It is true - the question was posted by me and now I realise that a) the circuit does not deal with 3 phase and was purely to get some pointers as to what I was dealing with - actually all the (semi-negative and non-negative) answers gave me a lot of reference and reading material. It all helps